# Safari is renaming downloaded files- can I change this?

Tags: html, download, safari

My image search site includes a download link, with the download tag in the a element. This correctly forces the browser to download the file as expected. However, a Safari user reports that Safari is automatically adding a .txt extension, requiring him to manually change it on each file.

As far as I can tell, using the simple HTML tag doesn't allow me to do anything other than rely on the browser to complete the download. The files themselves have plain text headers, which I imagine Safari must be interpreting and boldly deciding to make a change over.

So, is there something I can do to communicate to the browser better? Or a different download method that might be compatible? I am using Node and React on this, so more advanced options are possible. They just seem like a lot of effort and computational overhead for a basic link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference: this is defined by Apache's MIME type configuration in apache.conf (in my case). Chrome appears to trust files to be what they are, but Safari relies on the MIME header and creates its own dynamic extensions. This had to be set to 'image/fts' to register correctly. Being not a Mac user I hadn't run into this sort of thing before.